RegEx in Python
I'm trying to search for a word (single or multiple occurance(s)) in a sentence.
Example
strings = ["He likes walking","I like that","He said he liked the movie"]

If I want to search for "like" and in return get the flavour of like, what should be done?
I tried with following
keyword = "like"
for string in strings:
    p = regex.search(keyword+".*" ,string,flags=regex.IGNORECASE)
    print(p.allcaptures())
    print(p.group())

Problem with both these is it returns all words after like"*"
The output I'm expecting is ["likes","like","liked"]

What about #like and likes! You could for example split and check the individual parts.

What if your word is "day", should "daily" be matched? Or "maintain"... should "maintenance" be matched?

`"like\w*" would give you like followed by any word characters (i.e., in the same word) ... although such types of searches are fraught in real life if you rely too much on the consistency of English grammar as noted in previous comments ...

@topsail - Thanks. It worked.

This keyword+".*" means you're searching for the keyword and then everything after it. The . matches any character except a linefeed. What you want is only word characters, which is \w. Change the . to \w and it should do what you want.
